# c++ exception access violation with int variable

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

I have an really estrange error. I got an object attribute of int type called currentState

here is the declaration

```
class WorkerAgent : public BaseAgent {

private:
    int currentState;
```

The code below runs a lot of times inside a loop of a game but SOMETIMES (in a random time) the code chashes the program at the line (270)

*OBS: currentState is initialized already when running this line of code (270)!

```
if (currentState == REPAIRING) {

    if (!unit->isRepairing()) {

        setState(GATHER_MINERALS);
        BaseAgent* base = AgentManager::getInstance()->getClosestBase(unit->getTilePosition());

        if (base != NULL) {

            unit->rightClick(base->getUnit());
            return;
        }
    } else {

        return;
    }
}

int cur = currentState; // (line 270) 
bool b = cur == FIND_BUILDSPOT;
```

I have an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION and the program chashes.. I dont know can be happening since `currentState` is not a pointer neither `cur`

Error

```
VERSION: 1.16.1.1
BWAPI:
  REVISION: 4160
  BUILD: RELEASE
  ERROR: None
  LOCATION: Single Player 
MAP: Stepping Stones
     (3)Stepping Stones.scm

EXCEPTION: 0xC0000005    EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
FAULT:     0x10044217    BWAPI.dll
REGISTERS:
  EDI: 00000140
  ESI: 00000003
  EBX: 00000000
  EDX: C208C483
  ECX: 5B46A60C
  EAX: 035F0001
  EBP: 0018EEE8
  EIP: 10044217
  ESP: 0018E4C4
STACK:
  BWAPI.dll         0x10044217      ----
  BWAPI.dll         0x10046C38      ----
  BWAPI.dll         0x10047A43      ----
  BWAPI.dll         0x100408C6      ----
  DUMB.DLL          0x5B4254A0    WorkerAgent::computeActions
    d:\programming\mestrado\bots\dumb\bthaimodule\source\workeragent.cpp:270
```

Any other information about the case, please ask me! I'am getting crazy with this problem!

Comment: Is `currentState` initialized or otherwise given a value?

Comment: yes! currentState is initialized already!

Comment: Where the hell is line 270?

Comment: int cur = currentState; // (line 270)

Comment: Uninitialized was the most relevant thing I had. Now I suspect some other undefined behaviour if it's crashing on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentState` is a member of your class `WorkerAgent`, which means you have to have a valid object of type `WorkerAgent` for `currentState` to exist.

You're probably using an invalid (null, uninitalized, deleted, or otherwise garbage) pointer to a `WorkerAgent` in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: but why the code `if (currentState == REPAIRING) {` that is that before the line 270 doesnt crashes?

Comment: @thiagoh, Because undefined behaviour.

Comment: I dont think so you're right.. because this code runs inside a method of WorkerAgent!

Comment: @thiagoh: I don't know; that does seem odd. Examine your code and determine whether you actually have a valid `WorkerAgent` object.

Comment: @thiagoh: That doesn't prove anything. If you call `ptr->method()` when `ptr` is an invalid pointer, the behavior is undefined; the compiler isn't required to detect the error, but your program can misbehave in arbitrary ways.

Comment: @KeithThompson how can I verify it before call the method.. in other words.. how can I avoid that??

Comment: @thiagoh: With difficulty. You can test whether a pointer is null, but not whether it's invalid in some other way. You just have to write your code carefully so you don't use invalid pointers in the first place. Carefully examine the logic of your program. If you can narrow the problem down to a small complete example that exhibits the problem, post it in your question (unless doing that lets you solve the problem yourself). Are you using a pointer to a `WorkerAgent`? If so, where did that pointer get its value?